# C# get back to the beginning of the program

Tags: c#, if-statement, error-handling

I'm a beginner in programming and I've started out with C# not long ago. My question is, how do I get back to the start of this small program if the user enters a smaller number to the second slot?

here is the code:

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;

  namespace FizzBuzz
  {
   class Program
   { 
       static void Main(string[] args)
    {



        Console.Write("Starting number?     ->    ");
        int number1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        Console.Write("Ending number?     ->    ");
        int number2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        if (number1 >= number2)
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting number has to be smaller than the ending number!");

        }

        var number = new Queue<int>();
        number.Enqueue(9999);
        int fizzorbuzz = number.Dequeue();



        for (int i = number1; i < number2; i++)
        {
            number.Enqueue(i);
        }

        foreach (int i in number)
        {
            if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("FIZZBUZZZ");
            }
            else if (i % 5 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Buzz!");
            }
            else if (i % 3 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Fizz!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                break;
            }
          }
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Use a [while loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/2aeyhxcd.aspx) and only break out of that loop if the user performs an action that should cause the application to exit (which is for you to decide upon). Just be careful when coding a while loop to ensure you don't have an infinite loop, though there are obviously ways to force close an application anyway

Comment: While(userEnteredValue < second slot)

Comment: You also may want to use int.TryParse;

Comment: For this simple requirement, you don't have to go back to the start, you only have to get the user to enter the 2nd number again.  Put the while loop round the 2nd number until it is correct.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers, I came up with a solution based on what u guys said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution based on all the helpful code I got from you all.

This is what I had in mind, it works just like I wanted:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FizzBuzz
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int smallerNumber = 0;
        int biggerNumber = 0;

        bool running = true;

        while (running)
        {
            Console.Write("Starting number?     ->    "); 
            smallerNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


            Console.Write("Ending number?       ->    ");
            biggerNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


            if (smallerNumber >= biggerNumber)
            {
       Console.WriteLine("Starting number has to be smaller than the ending number!");

            }
            else
            {
                running = false;
            }
        }

        var number = new Queue<int>();
        number.Enqueue(9999);
        int fizzorbuzz = number.Dequeue();
        for (int i = smallerNumber; i < biggerNumber; i++)
        {
            number.Enqueue(i);
        }
        foreach (int i in number)
        {
            if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("FIZZBUZZZ");
            }
            else if (i % 5 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Buzz!");
            }
            else if (i % 3 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Fizz!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int number1;
int number2;
do{    
Console.Write("Starting number?     ->    ");
number1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());            

Console.Write("Ending number?     ->    ");
number2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

if (number1 >= number2)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Starting number has to be smaller than the ending number!");
}                
} 
while (number1 >= number2);
```

Comment: condition in while is wrong..OP wants smaller number in second number

Comment: Yeah noticed the text in the question says that, but the message he's displaying is saying first number should be smaller.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to a simple `while` loop, consider also this reusable scenario

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while(DoJob()) {}
}

static bool DoJob()
{
    ...
        return true; // want restart
    ...
    return false; // want exit
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]You can use something like do..while loop as shown below :-

```
    int number1, number2;
   do{    
        Console.Write("Starting number?     ->    ");
        number1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        Console.Write("Ending number?     ->    ");
        number2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

   }while (number1 <= number2);
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting number has to be smaller than the ending number!");
    }
```